# Find duplicates in list and add successive alphabetic characters after each one

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
List1 = ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M6', 'M7', 'M7', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10', 'M10', 'M10', 'M11']
```

And I want to find all the duplicates and then add lowercase alphabetic characters after each such that it looks like this:

```
List1 = ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5a', 'M5b', 'M5c', 'M6', 'M7a', 'M7b', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10a', 'M10b', 'M10c', 'M11']
```

I can find the duplicates, but I am not really sure what to.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you can just get rid of the duplicates by converting it into a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
import string, collections
def addition(val, _i, l):
   return string.ascii_lowercase[sum(c == val for c in l[:_i])]

List1 = ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M6', 'M7', 'M7', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10', 'M10', 'M10', 'M11']
c = collections.Counter(List1)
new_results = ['{}{}'.format(a, '' if c[a] == 1 else addition(a, i, List1)) for i, a in enumerate(List1)]
```

Output:

```
['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5a', 'M5b', 'M5c', 'M6', 'M7a', 'M7b', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10a', 'M10b', 'M10c', 'M11']
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much. Though, I'll be honest, I don't 100% understand exactly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way using `Counter` and `enumerate`:

```
from collections import Counter

List1 = ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M5', 'M5', 'M6', 'M7', 'M7', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10', 'M10', 'M10', 'M11']

c = Counter(List1)

prev = List1[0]
for i, x in enumerate(List1):
    if c[x] > 1 and prev != x:
        l = 'a'
        List1[i] += l
        prev = x
    elif c[x] > 1 and prev == x:
        l = chr(ord(l) + 1)
        List1[i] += l

print(List1)
# ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5a', 'M5b', 'M5c', 'M6', 'M7a', 'M7b', 'M8', 'M9', 'M10a', 'M10b', 'M10c', 'M11']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible soultion with a one-liner:

```
List2 = [x if List1.count(x) == 1 else x + chr(ord('a') + List1[:i].count(x)) 
         for i, x in enumerate(List1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution should solve your problem in a single pass - a single run through of the array. Much more performing than the solution by Ajax1234, austin and taras . Of course you can compress this code even more.

```
count = -1
newList = []
for indx,ele in enumerate(List1):
    if indx == 0:
        continue
    if List1[indx]==List1[indx-1]:
        count+=1
        newList.append(List1[indx-1]+str(chr(97+count)))
    elif count == -1:
        newList.append(List1[indx-1])
    else:
        count+=1
        newList.append(List1[indx-1]+str(chr(97+count)))
        count = -1
if count == -1:
    newList.append(List1[indx])
else:
    count +=1
    newList.append(List1[indx]+str(chr(97+count)))
```